# Selecting a multi-dimensional array in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, multidimensional-array

I have a task where I need to translate a DataTable to a two-dimensional array.  That's easy enough to do by just looping over the rows and columns (see example below).

```
private static string[,] ToArray(DataTable table)
{
    var array = new string[table.Rows.Count,table.Columns.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; ++j)
            array[i, j] = table.Rows[i][j].ToString();

    return array;
}
```

What I'd really like to do is use a select statement in LINQ to generate that 2D array.  Unfortunately it looks like there is no way in LINQ to select a multidimensional array.  Yes, I'm aware that I can use LINQ to select a jagged array, but that's not what I want.

Is my assumption correct, or is there a way to use LINQ to select a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: Could you do an array of arrays instead?  (it would be faster to convert)

Comment: Yes, I can do a jagged array (array of arrays), but unfortunately in this case that's not what the api I was calling would accept.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. My reasoning is that [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) and most other LINQ functions require that the collections they work on implement at least `IEnumerable<T>` for some T:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TResult> selector
)
```

A rectangular array doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` for any T so it can't be the return value of a Select function.

Comment: Yes, it's trivial to get a jagged array using LINQ, but a true 2D array is something else entirely.