# System.Array to POCO using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, system.array

I am reading in data from an Excel sheet so I have this code to get the region I want;

```
Excel.Range range = (Excel.Range)worksheet.get_Range("A9", "AO" + (worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).ToString());
System.Array rangeCells = (System.Array)range.Cells.Value;
```

So my Data is x long and 41 cells wide so my array looks like;

```
rangeCells[1,1] through to rangeCells[1,41] is line 1
rangeCells[2,1] through to rangeCells[2,41] is line 2
```

and so forth until the end.

Does anyone know of a LINQ way to get each line into an object?

Comment: Why do you need LINQ?

Comment: What would the object look like?

Comment: @I4V Why do you need air to breathe?

Comment: @I4V Why do I need linq? Because itterating through the whole collection building POCO's manually does not seem efficient.

Comment: p.s.w.g the object would look like a class that has 41 properties in it.  The names of which, i don't think, are relevant to the question.

Comment: Efficient in _what way_? Efficient in how ugly/clean your code is and how easy it is to maintain? Or efficient in how fast it executes at runtime?

Comment: @griegs It looks like you're using a multi-dimensional array, which it doesn't sound like linq can handle. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562817/selecting-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-linq

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, I guess in terms of clean code.  There are only going to be around 200 lines in this sheet so it's going to be fast no matter what.  However I'd just like to have less code and less manual object creation.  This isn't one of those questions that's going to make or break the application, this is a nice to have

Comment: @griegs So you'd have some kind of code like `new myObj() { Prop1 = rangeCells[1,0], Prop2 = rangeCells[1,1], SomeOtherProp = rangeCells[1,3], YetAnotherProp = rangeCells[1,4] .... };` for all 41 properties, but somehow condensed/cleaner/automated via LINQ (or other mechanism?) (EDIT: and of course incrementing the row)

Comment: @HighCore Don't comment just to comment. Linq is good but not necessary. griegs, Linq wouldn't make your code more efficent.

Comment: @RandomWebGuy, it is a multidimension array yeah and by the looks of that link, and my own trials, i think you may be right.  write this as an answer

Comment: @I4V, Oh I know it won't be more efficient, like I said, this is a nice to have to make the code look a little cleaner is all.

Comment: @griegs Would it really? Seems like two nested loops that `yield return` the object you want would be clean enough. Certainly cleaner than the mess of `Enumerable.Range()`s to do so with LINQ methods.

Comment: @griegs Actually, scratch that, apparently you can `foreach` over a multidimensional array.

Comment: @millimoose, really?  Hadn't even considered that.  Taking a look now.  And Yield might not be a bad approach either

Comment: @griegs Going by RandomWebGuy's links, it seems that multidimensional arrays do, however, implement non-generic `IEnumerable`. So `range.Cells.Value.Cast<whatever>().Select()` is also an option.

Comment: @millimoose, Ah, right.  Just finished the loop and manual poco creation but will take a look at this later today.  thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible because multi-dimensional arrays do not impliment `IEnumerable`

Discussed more:

- [Why do C# Multidimensional arrays not implement IEnumerable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275073/why-does-c-sharp-multidimensional-arrays-not-implement-ienumerablet)
- [Selecting a multi-dimensional array in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562817/selecting-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-linq)
- [Generate a two dimensional array via LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781172/generate-a-two-dimensional-array-via-linq)

Comment: @AbeMiessler Seeing as LINQ-to-Objects is a set of extension methods over `IEnumerable(T)`, the fact that only onedimensional arrays implement that interface would be a sticking point.

Comment: @KevinBabcock If by "ways around that" you mean doing something to flatten the array, then you're not really working with a 2D array anymore. (I admit this is splitting hairs, but the ambiguity alone means this answer isn't wrong per se, if not particularly helpful.)

Comment: @millimoose agreed (removed my comment)