# Problem in List<double[,]>

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

What is wrong with this (in C# 3.0):

```
List<double> x = new List<double> { 0.0330, -0.6463, 0.1226, -0.3304, 0.4764, -0.4159, 0.4209, -0.4070, -0.2090, -0.2718, -0.2240, -0.1275, -0.0810, 0.0349, -0.5067, 0.0094, -0.4404, -0.1212 };
List<double> y = new List<double> { 0.4807, -3.7070, -4.5582, -11.2126, -0.7733, 3.7269, 2.7672, 8.3333, 4.7023,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };

List<double[,]> z = new List<double[,]>{x,y}; // this line
```

The error produced is:

```
Error: Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<double>' to 'double[*,*]'
```

Help needed.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do. Do you want a `List<List<double>>`? or a `List<double[,]>`?

Comment: The error message is spot on, you're trying to convert a list of doubles into a 2-dimensional array of doubles. What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var z = new List<List<double>> { x, y };
```

However if you want to store your two lists in a twodimensional array ([,]) [this is your anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678178/how-can-i-convert-a-list-to-a-multi-dimensional-array). You will have to convert it manually as shown there:

```
public static T[,] To2dArray(this List<List<T>> list)
{
    if (list.Count == 0 || list[0].Count == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("The list must have non-zero dimensions.");

    var result = new T[list.Count, list[0].Count];
    for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
        {
            if (list[i].Count != list[0].Count)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The list cannot contain elements (lists) of different sizes.");
            result[i, j] = list[i][j];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`double[,]` defines a multidimensional array but you are specifying two Lists.

From your Initialization it looks like you are looking for something like

```
List<PointF> list = new List<PointF> { new PointF (0.0330F, 0.4807F), new PointF (-0.6463F, -3.7070F) };
```

Answer (score 0):

The collection initializer for `List<double[,]>` expects elements of type `double[,]` (which is a two-dimensional array, similar to a matrix), but you're passing it `x` and `y`, which are of type `List<double>`, which means it's trying to add two lists of doubles as the elements of the new list.

If you're trying add coordinates to the list, then you need a structure of some sort to contain them. You could write your own or you could use [`System.Drawing.PointF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pointf.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Are you after something like this?

```
        List<double> x = new List<double> { 0.0330, -0.6463, 0.1226, -0.3304, 0.4764, -0.4159, 0.4209, -0.4070, -0.2090, -0.2718, -0.2240, -0.1275, -0.0810, 0.0349, -0.5067, 0.0094, -0.4404, -0.1212 };
        List<double> y = new List<double> { 0.4807, -3.7070, -4.5582, -11.2126, -0.7733, 3.7269, 2.7672, 8.3333, 4.7023, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

        List<double[]> z = x.Select((x1, index) => new double[2] {x1, y[index]} ).ToList();
```

EDIT: changed my answer to join the lists on the index correctly instead of looking it up.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
List<List<double>,List<double>> z = new List<List<double>, List<double>>{x,y};
```

But I don't think that is really what you're after is it?