# Converting List<T> to Array (multidimensional)

Tags: c#, .net, list, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert a list<> to a multi-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678178/how-can-i-convert-a-list-to-a-multi-dimensional-array)

I want to have an array in form of `double[,]` for this purpose since I do not know what will be the length of this array, I want to make a `List` first then later using `List<T>.ToArray()` convert it to `double[,]`:

```
public double[,] FilterClampedData(double[,] data)
{
    var finalData = new List<double[]>();

    //Do some stuff on parameter

    return finalData.ToArray(); ///Does not compile :(
}
```

Comment: A `List<double[]>` can only possibly be converted to a `double[,]` if the arrays are all the same length.  It could be converted to a `double[][]` easily (that's what `ToArray` returns).  If this isn't clear to you, compare http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca

Comment: Your method signature indicate a 2D dimensional array as return, while you are returning a single dimensional array. In fact, you are returning an array of array.

Comment: what if your return value is `double[][]`

Comment: "No. In fact, these aren't necessarily compatible arrays" http://stackoverflow.com/a/678211/284240

Comment: This not the first time I've seen this question on SO.

Comment: Why not return an `IList<IList<double>>`?

Comment: Return should be `double[,]` since its needed buy another method somewhere else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `ToArray` returns a one-dimensional array, there is no wonder why this does not compile. If you were returning `double[][]`, it would compile, however. You could also build your 2-D array manually with two nested loops:

```
var R = finalData.Count;
var C = finalData[0].Length;
var res = new double[R, C];
for (int r = 0 ; r != R ; r++)
    for (int c = 0 ; c != C ; c++)
        res[r, c] = finalData[r][c];
return res;
```

The code above assumes that you have at least one item in the `finalData`, and that the length of all lists inside `finalData` is the same.

Comment: you mean `finalData.Count` ? I cant find .Length property

Comment: @Sean87 Absolutely, you're right, it's `Count`, not `Length`.

Comment: I guess the OP would already know `C` unless the result is jagged.

Answer (score 1):

`finalData.ToArray()` will produce `double[][]` because:

- `List<T>.ToArray()` returns `T[]`
- `List<T[]>.ToArray()` returns `T[][]`

Comment: Isn't this contradicting with the `exactly opposite statement` here [first line] - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11295805/763026 ?

Comment: @AngshumanAgarwal: "Since ToArray returns a one-dimensional array" - yes, it's correct and equals to my statement. List<T>.ToArray() returns T[]. List<T[]>.ToArray() returns T[][].

Answer (score 1):

1. Instantiate a new double array with the largest size [length of the list, largest array length in the list]
2. Walk through the list with double for cycle (first on the list, the nested on the current list item) and fill the new array